# Change Replication Snapshot location?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Is it possible in SQL Server 2005 to change where the snapshot for replication is generated? I need to generate it on a different HDD then the default. This is due to a disk space issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC working_directory column in MSdistpublishers table in msdb.